# Using @InjectMocks with a class whose constructor throws an exception. Is it not possible?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

```
public class MyObject {
    private Random random;
    //other attributes here
    
    public MyObject() throws Exception {
        this.random = new Random();

        //rest of the constructor here

    }

}
```

```
public class MyObjectTest {
    @Mock(name = "random")
    Random mockRandom;

    @InjectMocks
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

    //rest of the test here
}
```

The only problem is the IDE doesn't like this line:

MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

This is because the MyObject constructor throws an exception. But I can't, as far as I know, handle the exception on that line. But on the other hand I need to declare it like that there or Mockito gives an error.

Anything I'm missing or something else I can try? I just need to inject the mock Random for use in the constructor so that it always uses the same 'random number'(I already have the when().thenReturn() code sorted for the mockRandom so it's just the injection problem I can't figure out).

I rewrote the code for MyObject so that the constructor takes a Random as a parameter. That made it easy to pass it the mockRandom and make it use the same "random" result every time. It just felt a bit forced and doesn't feel right to me to have to have the code pass MyObject a Random every time I need a new MyObject (that's my inexperienced gut feeling anyway).

Answer (score 0):

`@InjectMocks` isn't going to initialize anything without telling the test framework what to do.  Try this:

```
@ExtendWith(MocktioExentsion.class)  // tell the test framework to use Mockito
public class MyObjectTest {
    @Mock(name = "random")
    Random mockRandom;

    @InjectMocks // will no do anything without the class level @ExtendWith(MocktioExentsion.class)
    //MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
    MyObject myObject;  // Mockito will initialize the object with the injected mock
```